# Fatal error: Class 'Slim\app' not found in locally it works but Error on Hosting

Tags: slim-3

I tried to upload it on hosting, but I get message Fatal Error, I tried locally just fine it works, is there any setup?

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../libs/NotORM.php';
//config
//$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

//use \Slim\App;

//$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = new \Slim\app;

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'secret';
$dbpass = 'blablabla';
$dbname = 'unit';
$dbmethod = 'mysql:dbname=';

$dsn = $dbmethod.$dbname;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db  = new NotORM($pdo);

//define app home
$app-> get('/', function(){
echo "Yoho ^_^";
});
//run App
$app->run();
```

And here my composer

```
{
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is composer installed and the vendor folder in the hosting server? If not, you need to put it on there either by doing `composer install` on the server or moving the local vendor folder over.

Comment: it was fixed with upgrade php vesion to >= 5.5